# Query in influxDB where tag is boolean

Tags: influxdb

I can make a query in influxDB:

```
SELECT * FROM raw
```

but I can't make a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM raw WHERE "to_compute"=true
```

I get no results

`to_compute` is a tag, it is supposed to be boolean, but I can only find types for fields.

In the [FAQ](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#why-can-t-i-query-boolean-field-values), I can only find an example with fields but not with tags.

How can I make this query ?

Answer (score 2):

Tags values in InfluxDB are always strings.
So I guess the value could be 'true' as a string.

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/concepts/glossary/#tag-value

What does it show you in the results when you run `SELECT * FROM raw` ?